# Copying contents of a folder from point A to B using a batch file and OpenFolderBox dialog

Tags: batch-file, dialog, copy, directory

I've been searching for some ways to copy a folder from the source to target using the OpenFolderBox dialog.

One of my friends helped me with it. I remember it used to work fine but now I dunno why it doesn't copy the contents. here's the batch source he wrote for me:

```
SET Target=Default Target
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('OpenFolderBox.exe /MD ^|^| ECHO Error^& IF ERRORLEVEL 2 ECHO Cancel') DO SET Target=%%A
SET Target

IF "%Target%"=="Cancel" (
exit
)

else

copy c:\source *.* %Target%
explorer  %Target%
```

and here's the OpenFolderBox dialog:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/dialogboxes.zip

BTW, I also need to have the default start directory of OpenFolderBox as "c:\" than the "current path"

Comment: I forgot to mention that I even tried to replace "copy c:\source" with "xcopy /s c:\source" but it didn't work...

Comment: I guess I figured out how to set the default directory for OpenFolderBox... all I did was edit the .cs source file inside the zip and replace the "string startfolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory( );" to "string startfolder = @"c:\";" and finally exported it to exe... I'm not sure what I did was right but fortunately it fixed the issue...  there's only one problem left...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured it out:

```
SET Target=Default Target
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('OpenFolderBox.exe /MD ^|^| ECHO Error^& IF ERRORLEVEL 2 ECHO Cancel') DO SET Target=%%A
SET Target

IF "%Target%"=="Cancel" (
exit
)

else (

xcopy /s /y "c:\source" "%Target%"
explorer  %Target%
)
```